# Xcode 12.2: Debugger not working with breakpoints

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using Xcode 12.2 (12B45b).
My issue is the breakpoints not work. I have tried re install command line tools, but it nothing change.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and turning on the option to 'Debug Executable' in Run->Debug Scheme fixed the issue for me.

May be related to this issue: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663823?page=1#640854022 [enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KewIk.png